# Does the phrase "over to" mean "on" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions, phrase-meaning, phrases

Could anyone please confirm that the phrase "over to" simply means "on" in the following sentence from the description of a game app:

> Want more?
>
> Tap **over to** the games category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that’s not quite the right meaning.

It’s the same as “drive over to the store” which asks someone to head over to the store via a car. In your sentence it’s just that your destination is the game category and you’re expected to tap to get there.

Notably, "over to" means "to". It’s common to have prepositions that are in essence redundant like this (for a longer example possible in this context, "on over to" also means "to")

Comment: ***over to*** here looks a bit like a "surface metaphor", where we could have used *Tap **through** to the games category* for more of a "container" metaphoric usage. But We probably wouldn't choose to use *Tap **into** the games category* because that particular combination is fairly well established with the specific sense of ***exploit, make use of***, as opposed to the required sense of ***go to***.